# How can I open the binding on this WW2 era Navy log?

Tags: world-war-two

I'd like to digitally archive this book (ww2 navy log). The pages were written before being bound in the book so it has to be taken apart to photograph the pages. Has anyone seen a book like this and can suggest how to handle the binding. The inside cover shows the empty book was manufactured by "Boorum & Pease". The middle bolt moves up and down and one side is a slightly loose but nothing else budges. Obviously, I don't want to tear it apart. Any suggestions?

Thanks
[image]

Comment: Try pulling the center pin towards you after you push it up. It should release and then the bar can be removed.

Comment: @justCal This worked (thanks) with the help of a flat head screwdriver but the head of the bolt broke off in the process. Oh well.

Comment: I was just going to warn you that it's probably a [sex bolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sex_bolt) (in German for example called _Buchschraube_) and may consist of two parts screwed together.